# Gradle: Bad <init> method call from inside of a branch (invokespecial)

Tags: groovy, gradle, verifyerror

Current versions of java (8u20, 7u67) break gradle\groovy compiler and runtime compatibility:

```
:compileTestGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
> Bad <init> method call from inside of a branch
  Exception Details:
    Location:
      some/MyClass.<init>(Lsome/MyOtherClass;)V @71: invokespecial
    Reason:
      Error exists in the bytecode
    Bytecode:
      0x0000000: b800 174d 04bd 0019 5903 2b53 5910 ff12
      0x0000010: 05b8 001f 2a5f ab00 0000 0055 0000 0003
      0x0000020: f20b c677 0000 0022 0000 9b75 0000 0037
      0x0000030: 2cce be6d 0000 0040 5f5a 5903 3212 05b8
      0x0000040: 0023 c000 055f 57b7 0026 a700 2b5f 5a57
      0x0000050: b700 29a7 0022 5f5a 5903 3212 2bb8 0023
      0x0000060: c000 2b5f 57b7 002e a700 0dbb 0030 5912
      0x0000070: 32b7 0035 bf57 2ab6 0039 4e2d 2a5f b500
      0x0000080: 3b2d 572c 123c 322a 123e b900 4403 0057
      0x0000090: b1                                     
    Stackmap Table:
      full_frame(@56,{UninitializedThis,Object[#74],Object[#76]},{Object[#78],UninitializedThis})
      full_frame(@77,{UninitializedThis,Object[#74],Object[#76]},{Object[#78],UninitializedThis})
      full_frame(@86,{UninitializedThis,Object[#74],Object[#76]},{Object[#78],UninitializedThis})
      full_frame(@107,{UninitializedThis,Object[#74],Object[#76]},{Object[#78],UninitializedThis})
      full_frame(@117,{Object[#2],Object[#74],Object[#76]},{Object[#78]})
```

People from ZeroTurnaround also noticed this behavior: 
http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/verifyerror-bad-method-call-from-inside-of-a-branch/

The question is simple: while we wait for any solution in next versions of java, is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most obvious way to deal with VerifyError is to use -noverify jvm option.

(Assuming gradle version >=1.12, and gradle wrapper as executable bin)

First of all, tell gradle to use the option for the compilation process (in your build.gradle):

```
compileGroovy {
    groovyOptions.forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-noverify']
}
```

For runtime, you should pass jvm option also:

Test task:

```
test {
    jvmArgs '-noverify'
}
```

If you use application plugin:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-noverify"]
```

Or, by any other means.

That'll be all. Happy waiting for java release with fix:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6951
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051012

Comment: Arun is correct. This is a JDK bug so updating to at least 7u72 should solve it for you.  I was experiencing the issue and after isntalling 7u72, my build works correctly.

Comment: I can't vote up this solution enough. It was maddening since nobody else in my group had this problem (they had different 1.7 JDKs).  Updating to u79 fixed me up.

Answer (score 5):

This is a jdk bug & it has been fixed in latest jdk version 7 u72

Comment: I upgraded from jdk1.8.0_20.jdk to jdk1.8.0_191.jdk and it seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It happens when `Constructor` calls super.

Adding `@CompileStatic` on `Constructor` solves the problem.

Comment: Simplest solution. Works great!